# BLKRRPART: Device or resource busy, scale up EBS root volume failed using growpart on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, fdisk

Usually i use growpart to rise up size of my root partition on aws, so that i don't have to reboot

For some reason in one of my instances, it doesn't work anymore:

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            993M  4.0K  993M   1% /dev
tmpfs           201M  668K  200M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      129G   55G   67G  46% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           1002M     0 1002M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user

# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/xvda: 161.1 GB, 161061273600 bytes
63 heads, 31 sectors/track, 161071 cylinders, total 314572800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8d503283

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1   *        2048   272629034   136313493+  83  Linux

# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   150G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   130G  0 part /

# growpart /dev/xvda 1
attempt to resize /dev/xvda failed. sfdisk output below:
| 
| Disk /dev/xvda: 161071 cylinders, 63 heads, 31 sectors/track
| Old situation:
| Units = cylinders of 999936 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0
| 
|    Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
| /dev/xvda1   *      1+ 139594  139594- 136313493+  83  Linux
| /dev/xvda2          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
| /dev/xvda3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
| /dev/xvda4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
| New situation:
| Units = sectors of 512 bytes, counting from 0
| 
|    Device Boot    Start       End   #sectors  Id  System
| /dev/xvda1   *      2048 314571662  314569615  83  Linux
| /dev/xvda2             0         -          0   0  Empty
| /dev/xvda3             0         -          0   0  Empty
| /dev/xvda4             0         -          0   0  Empty
| Warning: partition 1 does not start at a cylinder boundary
| Successfully wrote the new partition table
| 
| Re-reading the partition table ...
| BLKRRPART: Device or resource busy
| The command to re-read the partition table failed.
| Run partprobe(8), kpartx(8) or reboot your system now,
| before using mkfs
| If you created or changed a DOS partition, /dev/foo7, say, then use dd(1)
| to zero the first 512 bytes:  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/foo7 bs=512 count=1
| (See fdisk(8).)
FAILED: failed to resize
***** WARNING: Resize failed, attempting to revert ******
Re-reading the partition table ...
BLKRRPART: Device or resource busy
The command to re-read the partition table failed.
Run partprobe(8), kpartx(8) or reboot your system now,
before using mkfs
***** Appears to have gone OK ****
```

Version of CLoud-Utils `0.27-0ubuntu9.2`, same version and newer ones work on another servers normally!

I tried partx:

```
# partx --update 1 /dev/xvda
partx: /dev/xvda: error updating partition 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.

As there was a newer release of growpart available, i just upgraded that package (On Debian 8 upgraded version from "0.26-2" up to "0.29-1" from backports repositories) and was able to resize my partition right after it.

Answer (score 0):

`parted -s -a opt /dev/sda "resizepart 3 100%"` worked for me.